# Query a M2M related field in Django

Tags: django

I have a Model `Return` in my projects like the following:

```
class Kit(models.Model):
   
    kit_name = models.CharField(max_length=500, default=0)
    kit_info = models.CharField(max_length=500, default=0)
    kit_client = models.ForeignKey(Client, on_delete=models.CASCADE)


class ReturnKits(models.Model):

    kit = models.ForeignKey(Kit, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    items = models.ManyToManyField(ReturnKitsProducts)


class Return(models.Model):

    transaction_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
    transaction_no = models.IntegerField(default=0, blank=True, null=True)
    is_delivered = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    kits = models.ManyToManyField(ReturnKits)
```

How can I select all the `Return` objects which contains the `kit` with `kit_client` = 4?

I know we can query directly related objects using `__` but how to query nested ones ?

Comment: Do you mean select all `ReturnKits`? Your `Return` model doesn't seem to be related to the others in your code.

Comment: @Danoram Sorry, I have updated the question

Answer (score 0):

You can continue traversing the relationships with continued `__` segments.

```
Return.objects.filter(kits__kit__kit_client=4)
```